# MySQL issue with HAVING

Tags: mysql, select

I have such query:

`SELECT price FROM orders WHERE user_id = 10 HAVING count(*) > 1`

It works but always returns only one row. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The function count(*) always will return only 1 record. Just think about it.

Comment: Can you please let us know what do you want to achieve using this query?

Comment: This query doesn't really make any sense, an explanation of your end goal would be very helpful.

Comment: I need to get all the orders (prices) that specific user have made

Comment: @elvenbyte, no it's not. If there's only one order the query will return nothing

Comment: If that's the case I don't think the `HAVING` is necessary at all. `SELECT price FROM orders WHERE user_id = 10`

Comment: Do you only want the orders if the user has more than one order?

Comment: @user1761022, actually I need to get orders of a user only in case he made more than one purchase

Comment: Yes then you can order based on purchase timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
o.price,
o.user_id
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN(
SELECT 
user_id
FROM orders 
WHERE 
user_id = 10 
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING count(*) > 1
) subQ
ON subQ.user_id = o.user_id
```

Comment: Of course, no problem. In the future try to clarify your goals a bit more, it will help you get an answer much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Because `HAVING` clause work with `GROUP BY` see [description](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) here

As mention in comment :-

> I need to get all the orders (prices) that specific user have made

You need not to use `HAVING` you can simply do like this:

```
 SELECT price FROM orders WHERE user_id = 10
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I have added GROUP BY, but nothin changed. The same single price but there has be two of them. `SELECT price FROM orders WHERE user_id = 10 GROUP BY user_id HAVING count(*) > 1` . Any suggestions?

Comment: I need to get orders of a user only in case he made more than one purchase

Comment: If you are saving order date in your db then you can order by date fields.

Comment: Yes, I have. But need not to order them but get all the prices he made  in a column

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` is an extension to `GROUP BY`. It cannot be used on its own. Documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use having with no grouping data, e.g.:

```
SELECT price FROM orders WHERE user_id = 10 HAVING price > 10
```

But if you use grouped data like count, sum, etc., you should add `group by`:

```
SELECT sum(price) FROM orders WHERE user_id = 1 group by user_id HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: `price > 10` or `sum(price)` is not what I need. Just need to get all the prices in a column, so then I can get an array of them

Answer (score 0):

Showing only records where a certain id appear multiple times (from [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927872/select-all-rows-from-sql-based-upon-existence-of-multiple-rows-sequence-numbers)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

In your case, you would like to show the prices of the orders of a certain ID. First we select a user_id and restrict the "multiple purchase" condition.
Then we inject this into the normal request

```
SELECT prices FROM orders 
WHERE user_id = 10 
AND user_id IN 
      (SELECT user_id FROM orders GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

This should work